# Gradle/Java start-up script for Linux not executable

Tags: java, gradle

There is a Java/Gradle project that uses the plugins *java* and *application*.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}
```

The *application* plugin creates two scripts, one is *.bat* for Windows, and the other is a *sh* script for Linux (and Mac OS X), and places these two scripts  into the distribution *.zip* file.

The problem is that the generated startup script for Linux has no "executable" attribute (even though the app is built under Linux).
Having to do `chmod a+x` is annoying.

**Question:** How do I make Gradle make the generated startup script executable?
(Preferably, in a platform-independent way.)

Comment: What version of Gradle? If you run `gradle build` and look in `build/scripts` is the script in the script in there executable? Wondering if the executable flag is lost when the script is zipped/unzipped.

Comment: gradle-6.2.1 ===

Comment: the same with gradle-6.5

Comment: @dnault yes, the _sh_ script in `build/scripts` ***is*** executable (but _.bat_ is not). And the scripts in _.tar_ are both executable, while the scripts in _.zip_ are not.

Comment: in addition, the default `zip` behaviour under Linux is to preserve the attributes

Answer (score 0):

The *executable* attribute **is there, but it is not shown,** neither by Midnight Commander (shown as cleared) nor by the built-in archive viewer (not shown). Midnight Commander clears this attribute when it unpacks the files; zip and the built-in archive viewer correctly restore the *executable* attribute.

Nevertheless, this will work only under Linux (and probably OSX).